# Double reference in different objects dataset

Tags: java, list, dictionary, data-structures, dataset

I have two sets of objects, A and B. Objects of type A contains different number of objects of type B in a list. Example: 
A1 - B1,B2 
A2 - B3,B4,B5,B6 
A3 - B7,B8,B9. 
I wish to merge all B-type items in a single list, and access them by the index (most concretely for using them as the data for a RecyclerViewAdapter), but keeping somehow the reference to the container A object (None on the objects can be modified and therefore I must use data structures).

I tried using a HashMap> but that way I can't access all the indexes of B items, and a HashMap would imply to get the A-type objects repeated with the subsequent unnecessary memory impact. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Make a list of `ABPair` items, where each `ABPair` refers to a `B` object and its corresponding `A` object.  If `List<ABPair> abList` is your list, then `abList.get(i).getB()` gets you the `B` item at index `i`, and abList.get(i).getA()` gets the corresponding `A` object.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
objectASet.stream().map(a -> {
    a.getB().stream.map(b -> new Pair<>(b, a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ).flatMap(list -> list.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What this code does is the following:

1. Iterate over the ObjectASet that contains the B objects in each A object.
2. Map each a to a list of javaFx pair objects of which the key is b and the value is the reference of a. If the b objects are not unique objects then you can swap b with a if you like.
3. flatmap means merge all the seperately created lists into one big list stream.
4. Collect this stream into a list.

Now you have a list containing pairs of which the key is b and the value is the a reference. You can reference a list by its index. Hope this solution helps you